# Not able to get see unity play mode on quest with quest link cable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, quest

I am using unity editor to build application on oculus quest
i wanted to check the and debug the application at development stage
so i connected the quest and laptop with the quest link cable and watched some of youtube video to setup unity
but when i connect quest link cable and click play on unity editor only i am able to hear audio but not able to see play mode on quest
can anyone please help am i missing something

I tried youtube tutorials to setup unity and quest
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSD798Ov2oY

Comment: When you press Play, do you see the Unity splash screen on the Headset before hearing the Audio?

Comment: Hi @DanBlackburn Thanks for the reply 
 i was not able to see anything on headset, 
somehow now i got the solution , instead of the oculus plugin for windows i changed to OpenXR did some settings changes, now able to see the unity play

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- Developer mode for Quest is turned on
- Oculus app is running on desktop and device is connected (green light)
  (if it is connected but theres red light try restarting the driver C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-drivers\oculus-driver.exe )
- Make sure in Unity Project for PC and Android settings in **XR Plug-in Management**,  ***Oculus*** is turned on and **Initialize XR on Startup** is checked
- In Oculus desktop app go to **Settings->General** and make sure **OpenXR Runtime** uses Oculus as active provider (it was the issue for me because previously I was developing for SteamVr headsets)

[image: Device is connected to PC]

[image: Oculus is enabled in Unity project]

[image: Oculus Runtime is active for OpenXR]